# angularjs mocking element for directive to add features

Tags: angularjs

I use angular js 1.0.3 and I try to test my directive.

we use jQuery that is loaded automatically by angular and is accessible as angular.element that is passed to directive.

how can I add properties to the element before directive is linked with scope???

```
var def = '<input data-my-directive="" />';

var scope = $rootScope.$new();
var linked = $compile(def);
// do something to add property something that jq is adding
var directive = linked(scope);
```

my directive is something like

```
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.jq-plugin-method();
}
```

and my target is element passed to directive after linkage.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. it is sufficient to add

```
var jqLite = angular.element;
jqLite.prototype.jq-plugin-method = function(c) {...};
```

before

```
linked = $compile(definition);
```

I was blind or something yesterday or maybe I was adding this line after compile and it was too late.